# Create multiple links automatically with a loop in Dokuwiki?

Tags: php, for-loop, dokuwiki

I was trying to find a way to create multiple links automatically in Dokuwiki.

I tried enabling php and using the following code:

```
<php>
for ( $counter = 1; $counter <= 3; $counter += 1) {
    echo "[[page$counter]]";
    echo $counter;

}
</php>
```

I thought that the "echo" would work like in HTML and its output would be interpreted by Dokuwiki as its own command

(creating 3 links), but instead of that I just get the following text output (no links):

> [[page1]]1[[page2]]2[[page3]]3

Any help on how to use a loop (not necessarily with PHP) in Dokuwiki to create multiple links?

THANKS!

Comment: The code is doing exactly what you asked it to do, printing page and then the number. If you want it to print links, then you need to tell it where to find the links, and then loop through them

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but what I meant was that, for example, if I was using PHP with HTML and I used echo "<b>Hello World<b>" it wouldn't just write "<b>Hello World<b>", but it would interpret the "<b>" and write "Hello World" in bold.

Dokuwiki DOES NOT need to know where the links are (or if they exist) to specify them

What I want it to do is to interpret the "[[ ]]"" to create links in Dokuwiki

Answer (score 0):

You should put you loop in a syntax plugin.

For example: take the [skeleton plugin](https://www.dokuwiki.org/devel%3asyntax_plugin_skeleton), replace the render function by:

```
function render($mode, &$renderer, $data) {
    for ( $counter = 1; $counter <= 3; $counter += 1) {
        $renderer->internallink("page$counter", "title$counter");
    }
    return true;
}
```

After [installing](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin_installation_instructions) it, the tag "<TEST>" will be substituted by an invocation of your plugin.

For more info you might want to check:

- The [documentation](https://www.dokuwiki.org/devel%3asyntax_plugins)
- The [nspages plugin](https://github.com/gturri/nspages/blob/c0f8c62ccc9c1f779d6a7e33d85a22ca390fed9b/syntax.php#L451) which use a loop to add internal links